# How to use struct/std::pair correctly?

Tags: c++

I am using struct in my project which has an unordered_map, I tried to put a struct or a pair of integers as key to the map, then manipulate the map, but couldn't compile, it says:

```
usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/hashtable_policy.h:1082:53: error: invalid use of incomplete type âstrruct std::hash<NAMESPACE::Span<int> >â
using __ebo_h1 = _Hashtable_ebo_helper<1, _H1>;

operator==(const unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>& __x,
 ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unordered_map.h:1388:5: note:   template  argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:48:0,

-----------------------------------------------------------
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/hashtable_policy.h: In instantiation of âstruct  std::__detail::_Hash_ccode_base<std::pair<int, int>, std::pair<const std::pair<int, int>, NAMESPACE::ConfigSet>, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::hash<std::pair<int, int> >, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, true>â:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unordered_map.h:100:18:   required from âclass std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, RTBKIT::ConfigSet>â
```

What's wrong? Here is my struct:

```
namespace MYNAMESPACE {

template<typename T>
//can pass in a list than a range for IntervalFilter
struct Span
{
    //no arg/two args not working for the template typename T
    //span(T lb, T ub);
    //span();

    T lowerBound;
    T upperBound;

    static Span
    createFromJson(const Json::Value & val); 


    void fromJson(const Json::Value & val);

    Json::Value toJson() const;

    bool empty() const;
    //didn't declare this template type, isIncluded is not used
    template<typename U> bool isIncluded(const U & value) const;

 };
 } //namespace

 #endif
```

The code use the struct:
     ...

```
 private:
    static constexpr unsigned PRIORITY = 0x1401; }
    //std::unordered_map<Span<int>, ConfigSet> data;
    std::unordered_map<std::pair<int,int>, ConfigSet> data;
    void setConfig(unsigned configIndex, const AgentConfig& config) {
         auto range = [] (int first, int last) {
         return std::make_pair(first, last);
         };
         //int l = config.rangeFilter.lowerBound;
         //int r  = configrangeFilter.upperBound;
         //data[config.rangeFilter].set(configIndex);
         data[range(config.rangeFilter.lowerBound, config.rangeFilter.upperBound)].set(configIndex);
    }

};
```

Comment: You don't show any use of `std::unordered_map` in your code.

Comment: It's in another struct, see above added portion @aschepler

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the standard does not define a `hash` specialization for `std::pair`.  The compiler is telling you (indirectly) that it doesn't know how to generate hash values for your keys.

You should define your own hash class and use it in your `data` declaration.  Something like this:

```
struct MyHash
{
  size_t operator()(std::pair<int, int> value) const
  {
    // I make no promise that this is a good hash function for your dataset.
    return value.first + value.second;
  }
};

std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, ConfigSet, MyHash> data;
```

Comment: The only change I'd make is casting one of the values before the addition, as signed integer addition overflow is undefined behavior: `return static_cast<ssize_t>(value.first) + value.second;` Or you could do a better hash function like `return (static_cast<size_t>(value.first) << sizeof(int)*8) | value.second;`

Comment: It compiled, thanks !, in order to find a pair in the map by key std::pair, do I need to use/declare bool operator== for the key(struct)? Or pair already able to compare if it's the same key?

Comment: `std::pair` has built in comparison operators for lexicographic ordering.  Its default `operator==` will work fine in your case.